# Sliding Search Bar Down and Simultaneously Resizing Sibling View

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiedgeinsets

I have a `UIView` -- call it `HomeView` that contains a `UITableView` and a `UISearchBar`. That is, they are subviews. These are added in `viewDidLoad` for `HomeView`. A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

[image]

As can be seen from these screenshots, the first item in the `UITableView` is hidden once the `UISearchBar` is displayed. Here is the relevant code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
  self.table_view = [UITableView.alloc.initWithFrame: self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
  self.table_view.bounds.origin.y += 44;
  self.table_view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
  // ^^^ This is the code I believe is one source of my problem



// Triggered when search button in nav bar is pressed

// code to calculate delta here

// Here's how the view is animated. The search bar frame
// is dropped down (works), and ideally, the tableview
// drops down exactly the same amount at the same time.
// If the action is to hide, then the inverse happens
// because +delta+ will have been calculated as a
// negative number above.
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.7
  delay: 0.0
  options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
  animations:^ {
    self.searchBar.frame = CGRectOffset(@searchBar.frame, 0.0, delta);
  }
  completion:^(BOOL finished){
    self.searchBarVisible = !self.searchBarVisible
    self.searchBar.hidden = !self.searchBarVisible
    edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, self.searchBarVisible ? delta : 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
    [tableView setContentInset: edgeInsets]
  }
];
```

What actually happens is that the search bar slides down as expected in response to the search button press and then slides up on next button press. However, the table view never adjusts.

The problem, as near as I can tell, is that in `viewDidLoad`, the enclosing `HomeView` has not been rendered, so the size is as-yet unknown. I can get the screen dimensions and use that, but I thought the auto resizing mask was better practice, right?

Are there obvious flaws in this, and is there a way to get the table view to animate down at the same time the search bar is?

Thanks

Comment: I hate to be that guy but why not just use a tableViewController? Doing so then following [this piece of apple sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848) would make it a lot easier than manually resizing views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, let's try this again!

In your animation block, change the line where you make edgeInsets to:

```
edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.searchBarVisible ? delta : 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

From what I can tell, the first argument is the top, and the one you had set was the left inset.

Comment: This works perfectly. Positional parameters are really screwing me up.